# Filling gaps with next not null value

Tags: sql, teradata, gaps-and-islands, ansi-sql, gaps-in-data

I've been trying to find a solution to this since some days ago. I have the following dataset.

```
|id|order|certain_event|order_of_occurrence|
|--|-----|-------------|-------------------|
|a |1    |NULL         |NULL               |
|a |2    |NULL         |NULL               |
|a |3    |NULL         |NULL               |
|a |4    |NULL         |NULL               |
|a |5    |4            |1                  |
|a |6    |NULL         |NULL               |
|a |7    |NULL         |NULL               |
|a |8    |4            |2                  |
|a |9    |NULL         |NULL               |
```

The desired output consists in replacing the null values from the **order_of_occurrence** column with the next non-null value. Like this:

```
|id|order|certain_event|order_of_occurrence|
|--|-----|-------------|-------------------|
|a |1    |NULL         |1                  |
|a |2    |NULL         |1                  |
|a |3    |NULL         |1                  |
|a |4    |NULL         |1                  |
|a |5    |4            |1                  |
|a |6    |NULL         |2                  |
|a |7    |NULL         |2                  |
|a |8    |4            |2                  |
|a |9    |NULL         |NULL               |
```

I've tried using a subquery for retrieving the non-null values from the order of occurrence column, but I get more than one value returned. Like the following:

```
SELECT a.*,
      CASE
         WHEN a.order_of_occurrence IS NOT NULL THEN a.order_of_occurence
         WHEN a.order_of_occurence IS NULL THEN (SELECT B.ORDER_OF_OCCURENCE FROM dataset AS B 
                                                 WHERE B.ORDER_OF_OCCURRENCE IS NOT NULL)
      END AS corrected_order
FROM dataset AS a
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple task for the IGNORE NULLS option in FIRST/LAST_VALUE:

```
last_value(order_of_occurrence IGNORE NULLS)
over (partition by id
      order by "order" DESC
      rows unbounded preceding)
```

Comment: This was precisely the option I needed! Thank you so much!!